# How to convert an xarray dataset to pandas dataframes inside a dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask, python-xarray

I have a calculation that expects a pandas dataframe as input. I'd like to run this calculation on data stored in a netCDF file that expands to 51GB - currently I've been opening the file with `xarray.open_dataset` and using chunks (my understanding is that this opened file is actually a dask array, so only loads chunks of data into memory at a time). However, I don't seem to be able to take advantage of this lazy loading, since I have to convert the xarray data into a pandas dataframe in order to run my calculation - and my understanding is that at that point all the data is loaded into memory (which is bad).

So I guess long story short, my question is: how can I get from an xarray dataset to a pandas dataframe without any intermediate steps that load my entire data into memory? I've seen dask work with `pandas.read_csv`, and I see it work with xarray, but I'm not sure how to convert an already opened netCDF xarray dataset to a pandas dataframe in chunks.

Thanks and sorry for the vague question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good question. This *should* be doable, but I'm not quite sure what the right approach is.

Ideally, we could simply implement a `xarray.Dataset.to_dask_dataframe()` method. But there are several challenges here -- the biggest one being that dask currently does not support [dataframes with a MultiIndex](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/811).

Alternatively, you might want to construct a list of `dask.Delayed` objects holding `pandas.DataFrames` for each chunk of the `xarray.Dataset`. Toward this end, it would be nice if xarray had something like dask.array's [`to_delayed` method](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/40213cc62c8d0f87f320d999f2a58a87c08513f7/dask/array/core.py#L1639) for converting a Dataset into an array of delayed datasets, which you could then lazily convert into DataFrame objects and do your computation.

I encourage you to open an issue on either the dask or xarray GitHub pages to discuss, especially if you might be interested in contributing code. EDIT: You can find that issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1093).